# Cretate multiple shared secrets in a (selfmade) public/privavte key infrastructure

Tags: encryption

I just try to understand cryptography, please be concern. Its not meant to be secure or professional. I create 3 numbers for each party. a public key, a secret key and a modulus. The first party (A) creates his keys

```
let pri = 133
let mod = 256
let pub = mod - pri
```

and shares "mod" and "pub" to other partys (B, C). When B want to encrypt a string he takes A's public key and modulus and do

```
// B encrypts
let enc = ( input + pubA ) % modA
```

A on his side is doing

```
// B decrypts
let dec = ( enc + priA) % modA
```

to decrypt it. My problem is, i can create multiple keypairs but only 1 associated public key to each secret key because i have to share the modulus of each pair for en/decryption.

Is it possible (in this situation) to create multiple publics numbers for a single private number? And if so, how can i do it?

Thank you (and sorry if this is a poor question)

**EDIT** Even if its not "good" to create your own cipher i want to do so..

I recognized that i missed the secret exponent d so that phi divides (e * expo)-1.

```
/* Pseude code */

p = q = primes()
n = p * q
phi = (p-1) * (q-1)

e = 3
d = ? // <-- have to find my own secret exponent!

if( gcd(e, p-1) != gcd(e, q-1) ) exit(0)

expo = 0
for(expo < 100000)
    if( (e * expo)-1 == phi ) ) d = expo
```

And therefore i could have

```
public(n,e)
private(n,d)
```

so i can share (n,e). Is that correct?

Comment: Please see [Why is writing your own encryption discouraged?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43272/why-is-writing-your-own-encryption-discouraged)

Comment: A cipher is a tool used for encryption, its not an encryption itself, am i wrong?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher

Comment: @kelalaka I cant find different information. For example a XOR cipher. What have XORing and encrypting in common?

Comment: You should definitely watch some online courses.  Did you read Wikipedia? There is no X-or cipher. There is [One Time Pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) and [Stream Ciphers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher).

Comment: e.g. cesar cipher - do you really say cesar cipher is an encryption algorythm? You really should read your wikipedia link again.. A cipher is GENERATED by an encryption algorythm! Its not an algorythm itself!

Comment: From Wikipedia : `In cryptography, a Caesar cipher, also known as Caesar's cipher, the shift cipher, Caesar's code or Caesar shift, is one of the simplest and most widely known encryption techniques`

Comment: Its just a bit shifting based on a static shift, not a real mathematical encryption. exactely thats the point! If you know the number of bits to shift you can extract the cleartext, you dont need something like modulus or even prime numbers to do that! In german its called chiffre.

Comment: Can you call DES as cipher? it is breakable now!

Comment: No, its an algorythm and if you increase the number of bits (to >56) its (kind of secure) until now

Comment: If you increase the key size, it is no longer DES. It is a new encryption algorithm that needs new security analyzes. You don't accept the definitions and playing with the words. It is not upto  somebody to call Caesar cipher as cipher or not.  Vernam Cipher uses just x-or, before insulting it read about `perfect secrecy`.

Comment: Come on bro, wanna punk me? If you increase the bit size its Triple-DES, TDES, 3DES or DESede. Please read Wikipedia about DES. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard. For me, this discussion is closed. SO already force me to go to chat..